# Securing range hood with tile & concrete behind—should I pre-drill wider?

Tags: tile, fastener, range, concrete-block, hood

I need to secure a range hood on my new subway tile backsplash. Behind the tile is the thinset, drywall, then concrete block. I don't think my furring strips are ideally located for mounting purposes.

My plan is to use 1/4" Tapcons which require a 3/16" pilot hole. That's fine, but **should I first drill the full 1/4" through the tile, thinset, and drywall until I reach the block?** My concern is that driving the Tapcons through the tile and thinset at 3/16" could potentially crack the tile or affect the integrity of the thinset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that would be wise, particularly for the tile. You can drill a 1/4" or maybe 3/8" hole in the tile using a masonry bit in a non-hammering drill. Then switch the hammer mode on and pop in the 3/16" bit for the screw hole in the non tile layers.

Comment: This is probably what I'll do (5/16" is the best I can do around here, probably with [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Milwaukee-5-16-in-Diamond-Plus-Mini-Hole-Saw-49-56-0507/204994401)). But I actually thought I may drill 3/16" through the tile first, that way I can just switch to my masonry bit and drill the pilot for the Tapcons. Then I would go back and enlarge the hole I made in the tile. Not sure if I should use a step bit for that, but I think that way I can ensure that the 3/16" pilot hole is centered within the larger hole I put in the tile. How's that plan?

Comment: That sounds probably fine. My main concern would be that you do not use a drill in hammer mode on the tile. So I'd probably first drill through tile and just a bit into cement with the small bit in non-hammer mode, then expand the tile hole with the bigger bit (also in non-hammer mode), and finally deepen the hole with the small bit in hammer mode.